# Insert the Large Amount of Data in SQLite in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to inset the  2000 Rows in database table is there any way to insert the data very Fast.currenty i am using Below code for insert the data in database.

**Code :-**

```
+(NSString* )getDatabasePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Crocodilian"];
    return writableDBPath;

}

+(NSMutableArray *)executeQuery:(NSString*)str{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement= nil;
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *strPath = [self getDatabasePath];
    NSMutableArray *allDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (sqlite3_open([strPath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [str UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                            NSInteger i = 0;
                NSInteger iColumnCount = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                while (i< iColumnCount) {
                    NSString *str = [self encodedString:(const unsigned char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];


                NSString *strFieldName = [self encodedString:(const unsigned char*)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)];

                    [dict setObject:str forKey:strFieldName];
                    i++;
                }

                [allDataArray addObject:dict];
                [dict release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } 
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return allDataArray;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Then what's your Problem..? use FMDB is more easy then above your code.

Comment: insert all data in a single transaction. `commit` is heavy in `SQLite`

Comment: check this of setUp FMDB in to your project:-http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/

Comment: @NitinGohel FMDB supports for all ios version ?

Comment: Use [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) executing `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before you start inserting, and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` when done at the. Makes a _huge_ impact on performance.

Comment: @Rushabh While I'm a huge fan of FMDB (makes it much easier to write solid SQLite code), it won't, by itself, solve the problem. If you're going to use FMDB, you would want to use the equivalent calls, namely `beginTransaction` and `commit`. See [Transactions](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#task_Transactions) in the FMDB docs for more information.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your huge support i read your comments and i will change my code according to your comments thanks for supports :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, you are trying to insert one row at a time. SQLite adds commit after every insert. i had a similar issue of performance while inserting large data. I solved it using batch insert.

First create query with multiple inserts (don't need prepared statement in this case) and fire the query at once. This has major performance improvement. The only thing is that, you have to validate data before you are creating multiple insert query.

happy coding ..

Answer (score 2):

You can try Like this for Bulk insert

My Table is `Product(ProductID int,ProductName text,ShortDescription text)`

```
sqlite3 *dtdb;
const char *dbpath=//database path

   if ((sqlite3_open(dbpath,&dtdb)==SQLITE_OK))
    {

        sqlite3_exec(dtdb, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);


        char buffer[] = "INSERT INTO Product VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)";

        sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dtdb, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, NULL);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict=[array objectAtIndex:i];

            NSArray *arKeys=[dict allKeys];


            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt,1, [[dict objectForKey:@"ProductID"]intValue]);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"ProductName"]]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"ShortDescription"]]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);


            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                printf("Commit Failed!\n");
            }

            sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        }
        if(sqlite3_exec(dtdb, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"commited products all");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"commited  fail products all");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    }

    sqlite3_close(dtdb);
```